# A friend of me vs a friend of mine

Tags: possessives

> 1. He is a friend of mine.
> 2. He is a friend of me.
> 3. He is a friend of my father's.
> 4. He is a friend of my father.

Which of them are correct?
What is the difference between 3 and 4?

Comment: The answer to the difference between 3 and 4 can be found at http://english.stackexchange.com/q/12126/211388

Answer (score 1):

It is customary in English, though it may not make sense to you, to use the so-called "double possessive":

> He is a friend of mine.
>
> He is a friend of my father's.

Even in cases like

> That is a favorite book of mine.

Comment: I found both-one with double possesive and one without double possesive. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: There's not really a difference in meaning - it's just customary to have the double possessive.  In the case of a pronoun (as in your examples #1 and #2), it's required.  Of that group, #2 is the only one that is incorrect, but I would prefer #3 over #4.

Comment: @AbuNaimMuhammedKalil Personally, I think there is a slight difference in meaning as elucidated by PLL in another StackExchange, [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/12126/211388).