# "A car of the family" to mean "one of the family's car"?

Tags: meaning, possessives

Can we use the below expressions to mean "one of...."

> (1) A car of the family

to mean one of the family's cars?

> (2) A hat of the man

to mean one of the man's hats?

> (3) A son of the old man

to mean one of the old man's sons?

> (4) A car of a lawyer

to mean that there is a lawyer and what we're talking about is one of the lawyer's cars?

---

If we use the below expressions, do they mean the the things possessed are the only ones? Or it depends on the context?

> (5) The car of the girl

implies the girl has one car only ?

By the way, I know "the girl's car" is preferred, but "the car of the girl" is also correct, right?

> (6) The son of the old woman

implies the old woman has one son only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In (1) - (3), you need the last word to be in the possessive form, as explained [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/112867/a-friend-of-me-vs-a-friend-of-mine). As to (4), if the lawyer had been mentioned before, you could say *A car of the lawyer's*. It would sound odd if the lawyer was being mentioned for the first time, though. Better to say *A car belonging to a lawyer*.

Yes, using *The* X of Y usually implies that Y has only one X.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are "the car of the girl" or "the hat of the lawyer" correct? Can I use them? I have heard that animate beings are not usually used with that structure. What do you think?

Comment: In terms of the structure "The X of Y", do "the son of "an" old woman" imply that she has one son only?

Comment: They are _grammatically_ correct, but would never be used in ordinary speech, unless perhaps the speaker was going on to say something else about the owner. "That's the car of the girl I was telling you about earlier."

Comment: Thank you for reply. In terms of the structure "The X of Y", do "the son of an woman" 
 and "the son of the woman"  both imply that she has one son only? Does it depend on the context or emphasis?

Comment: On reflection, perhaps I was over-hasty in saying that - see [this earlier question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/268666/usage-of-article-the-the-son-of-austrlian-immigrants).

Comment: Thank you for providing another answer. I have read it. So, in conclusion, I can safely say "The X of Y" structures such as "the car of the girl" or "the hat of a rock star" don't imply how many the things are, right?

Comment: In almost all contexts, *structures such as "the car of the girl" or "the hat of a rock star"* just imply "non-native speaker". Native Anglophones in most contexts would refer to *the girl's car, a rock star's hat.* But any implication as to "how many" is contained in the ***article*** (***the** car of John's* = he probably only has one car; ***a** car of John's* = he probably has several cars).